# Como Reproducir 3 audios de forma consecutiva en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Que tal amigos, tengo tres archivos , si hago lo siguiente dentro del "onclick" de mi main activity:

```
MediaPlayer Audio1 = MediaPlayer .create(this, R.raw.Audio1);

MediaPlayer Audio2 = MediaPlayer .create(this, R.raw.Audio2);

MediaPlayer Audio3 = MediaPlayer .create(this, R.raw.Audio3);


Audio2.start();

Audio3.start();
```

Se reproducen de forma simultanea. Quisiera que alguien me brinde un código para poder resolver esto , he estado investigando opciones como MediaListener y el SoundPool pero las respuestas que encuentro son complicadas y no entiendo bien como aplicarlas. Si alguien tuviera un código sencillo y directo que funcione le agradecería, después me pongo a estudiarlo a detalle pero me urge resolver este detalle.

Comment: Hola Marco, lo que realizas no es una buena practica, no es necesario agregar controles para reproducir la misma cantidad de multimedia, debes implementar un control para reproducir en forma consecutiva todos. agrego respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas únicamente un `MediaPlayer` para la reproducción de los audios, si los vas a almacenar en `/raw` puedes crear un array con elementos tipo entero para la reproducción.

Recuerda siempre que los recursos deben definirse con nombres en minúsculas con letras de a-z, 0-9, o underscore "_":

```
   private int[] sounds = {R.raw.audio1, R.raw.audio2, R.raw.audio3};
```

al completar la reproducción de un audio detectada por medio de [**OnCompletionListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html), continua con el siguiente audio sucesivamente.

Este sería el ejemplo completo:

```
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    private final static String TAG = "MediaPlayer audios";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int[] sounds = {R.raw.audio1, R.raw.audio2, R.raw.audio3};
    private int sound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[0]);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        play();
    }

    private void play() {
        sound++;
        if (sounds.length <= sound){
            //Termina reproducción de todos los audios.
            return;
        }

        AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(sounds[sound]);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            afd.close();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException Unable to play audio : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException Unable to play audio : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException Unable to play audio : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y gracias por el código, es bien completo!

Comment: Un placer me da gusto haya sido de utilidad, no es necesario agregar varios  controles, con uno puede reproducir todo lo que requieres en tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

No se si entiendo bien pero quieres que al momento que termine una cancion se reproduzca otra?, puedes hacerlo con la funcion **setOnCompletionListener**

```
Audio1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        //Cuando acabe hara esta accion 
                        mp=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,Uri.parse(String.valueOf("/sdcard/rune.mp3")));
                        mp.start()
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda , en verdad funcionó!!!  :D