# MediaPlayer no funciona a veces

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mediaplayer

El problema no lo he localizado por ende tratare de ser lo mas especifico posible ya que el compiler no me tira ningun error y cuando pasa por test en el debugger tampoco, pero en algunos celulares ocurre un error muy peculiar el cual he intentado al menos identificar pero no doy con la respuesta

En algunos celulares cuando creo muchos MediaPlayer algunos a la hora de ser reproducidos no funcionan, para ser mas claro pondre el codigo que se explica por si solo.

```
        sonido1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sonido1);
        sonido2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sonido2);
        sonido3 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sonido3);
        sonido4 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sonido4);
```

Ejemplo evento click y start de un MediaPlayer

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(sonido1.isPlaying() ){
                    sonido1.pause();
                    sonido1.seekTo(0);

                    btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb806"));

                }else{
                    sonido1.seekTo(0);
                    sonido1.start();
                    btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e1a206"));
                }
            }

        });
```

La problematica es que en algunos celulares funciona sin problema y cuando lo compilo o lo testeo con un debugger no hay errores que pueda observar sin embargo en algunos celulares cuando hay muchos sonidos los ultimos no se reproducen como es debido Ejemplo el sonido18.

Espero haber sido lo mas claro y especifico posible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema principal es debido a que creas varias instancias de MediaPlayer, en realidad solo necesitas una instancia.

Muy importante hacer uso del listener [MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)  que 
es invocado cuando la fuente de medios esté lista para la reproducción, en este momento puedes llamar `.start()` .

Este es un ejemplo de acuerdo al codigo de tu pregunta:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private int[] sonidos = {R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2, R.raw.sound3, R.raw.sound4};
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         //Obtiene referencia de botones.
         btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
         btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
         btn3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);



        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(mediaPlayer !=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

                    btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb806"));

                }else{
                    playMedia(0);
                    btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e1a206"));
                }
            }

        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(mediaPlayer !=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

                    btn2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb806"));

                }else{
                    playMedia(1);
                    btn2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e1a206"));
                }
            }

        });

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(mediaPlayer !=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

                    btn3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb806"));

                }else{
                    playMedia(2);
                    btn3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e1a206"));
                }
            }

        });


    }

    /*Recibe el indice del medio a reproducir*/
    public void playMedia(int media){

        try {

            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sonidos[media]);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "inicia reproduccion!  ");
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }
            });


        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException Unable to play audio : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException Unable to play audio : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Revisa esta pregunta relacionada:

[Como Reproducir 3 audios de forma consecutiva en Android Studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73936/como-reproducir-3-audios-de-forma-consecutiva-en-android-studio)

Comment: Me gustaria agregar que puede llegar a ser util tambien hacer un mediaplayer release antes de hacer el create porque algunas veces si tocas muchos botones al mismo tiempo se medio que buggea