# Iniciar nueva actividad luego de que finaliza el video

Tags: android, android-studio, video

**Buenas, me gustaría hacer que al finalizar la reproducción de un video ubicado en la carpeta `raw` se inicie otra actividad automáticamente. Es decir, por ejemplo:

La actividad principal tiene un botón, al presionarlo inicia la actividad donde se reproduce el video automáticamente y una vez que este video se termine de reproducir, quiero que se inicie otra actividad.

**Main:**

```
//desde acá inicio la actividad del video
jugar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent iniciar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoIntroduccion.class);
                startActivity(iniciar);
            }
        });
```

**Esta es la actividad donde se reproduce el video:**

```
VideoView introVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_introduccion);

        introVideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.introVideo);

        Uri ubicacion = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.dafran.nowthegame/" +
                R.raw.intro);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        introVideo.setMediaController(mediaController);

        introVideo.setVideoURI(ubicacion);
        introVideo.start();
    }
```

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para determinar cuando un archivo de media completo su reproduccion en el caso de VideoView usa el listener [**OnCompletionListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html)

```
introVideo.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                     //Termina reproduccion,
                     //Realiza Intent. 
                      Intent iniciar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoIntroduccion.class);
                      startActivity(iniciar);
                    }
                });
```

Este es un ejemplo en donde se reproducen 3 audios consecutivamente detectando cuando se dejo de reproducir cada archivo

[Como Reproducir 3 audios de forma consecutiva en Android Studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74097/95)

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

```
introVideo.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                VideoIntroduccion.this.finish(); //para finalizar esta actividad

                Intent primerCapítulo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Introduccion.class);
                startActivity(primerCapítulo);
            }
        });
```